# Unable to build center () and text() widget

Tags: flutter, flutter-test

I am working on my new app. While creating the login page, i faced some issue. My code works fine till a point and after that point or line, it stops building more widgets.

My code(working portion):

```
void main() => runApp(
  MaterialApp(
    debugShowCheckedModeBanner:false,
    home: Background1(),
  ),
);


class Background1 extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold( //Whole screen
          body: Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
              width: double.infinity,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                gradient: LinearGradient(
                  begin: Alignment.topCenter,
                  colors: [
                    Colors.purple.shade700,
                    Colors.purple.shade500,
                    Colors.purple.shade300,
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[
                SizedBox (height: 80),
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                  child: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Text("LOGIN", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white,fontSize: 40,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(topLeft: Radius.circular(20), topRight: Radius.circular(20),bottomLeft: Radius.circular(20),bottomRight: Radius.circular(20)),
                      color: Colors.transparent,
                    ),
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                      child: Column(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          SizedBox(
                            height: 20,
                          ),
                          Container(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: Colors.white,
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                              boxShadow: [BoxShadow(
                                color: Color.fromRGBO(225, 95, 27, 0.3),
                                blurRadius: 20,
                                offset: Offset(0,10),
                              )],
                            ),
                            child: Column(
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Container(
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    border: Border(bottom: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey[200])),
                                  ),
                                  child: TextField(
                                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                                      hintText: "Email or phone number",
                                      hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
                                      border: InputBorder.none,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                SizedBox(height: 10),
                                Container(
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    border: Border(bottom: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey[200])),
                                  ),
                                  child: TextField(
                                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                                      hintText: "Password",
                                      hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
                                      border: InputBorder.none,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(height: 40),
                          Text("Forgot Password?", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
                          SizedBox(height: 40),
                          Container(
                            height: 40,
                            margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 50),
                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: Colors.purple.shade800,
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)),
                            child: Center(
                              child: Text("LOGIN", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                            ),
                          ),
],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Couldn't able to create center() and Text() widget, which is at the end of the code.

```
child: Text("LOGIN", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                            ),
                          ),
```

And also it doesn't build widgets as i write further. I've attached an image showing my emulator where it doesn't show LOGIN in white color on the purple button. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SzRYQ.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

just remove the padding of the container and it will work fine.

code after removing the container padding:

```
void main() => runApp(
      MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        home: Background1(),
      ),
    );

class Background1 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        //Whole screen
        body: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
          width: double.infinity,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            gradient: LinearGradient(
              begin: Alignment.topCenter,
              colors: [
                Colors.purple.shade700,
                Colors.purple.shade500,
                Colors.purple.shade300,
              ],
            ),
          ),
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[
              SizedBox(height: 80),
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text("LOGIN",
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            fontSize: 40,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                        topLeft: Radius.circular(20),
                        topRight: Radius.circular(20),
                        bottomLeft: Radius.circular(20),
                        bottomRight: Radius.circular(20)),
                    color: Colors.transparent,
                  ),
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                    child: Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 20,
                        ),
                        Container(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                            boxShadow: [
                              BoxShadow(
                                color: Color.fromRGBO(225, 95, 27, 0.3),
                                blurRadius: 20,
                                offset: Offset(0, 10),
                              )
                            ],
                          ),
                          child: Column(
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Container(
                                padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  border: Border(
                                      bottom:
                                          BorderSide(color: Colors.grey[200])),
                                ),
                                child: TextField(
                                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                                    hintText: "Email or phone number",
                                    hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
                                    border: InputBorder.none,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                              SizedBox(height: 10),
                              Container(
                                padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  border: Border(
                                      bottom:
                                          BorderSide(color: Colors.grey[200])),
                                ),
                                child: TextField(
                                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                                    hintText: "Password",
                                    hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
                                    border: InputBorder.none,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(height: 40),
                        Text("Forgot Password?",
                            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
                        SizedBox(height: 40),
                        Container(
                          height: 40,
                          margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 50),
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: Colors.purple.shade800,
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)),
                          child: Center(
                            child: Text("LOGIN",
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be using all of the space on the screen, rather then using a column use a listview, this will allow you to scroll. Additionally Listview.builder will allow you to build the children of the list view dynamically.
checkout https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListView-class.html for info on the listview class